# How can we make Use Case Model in UML for given Statement?

Tags: uml, use-case, model

I have the following statement for which I have to make Use Case Model. I have completed all the actors and use cases.

**Problem Statement**

*News Mobile Application offers its normal users to read/listen news about* *sports, entertainment, business, politics, and education etc. News mobile* *application is accessible in urban and remote areas using internet services. A*  *Member user can listen/read local news by enabling GPS service. Few additional* *services can also access by Member user including commenting on current affairs* *and managing his/her profile. A member user will register him/her using* *credentials on said mobile application. A member user can also be an analyst,* *reporter or an employee of institution. There is another stakeholder; Admin of* *this mobile application will work differently. The admin will monitor and* delete *fake or irrelevant news entered by member user and enter latest news. There are* *also full time hired reporters by news channel, which register by admin.*

I am stuck at the following points:

1. `News mobile application is accessible in urban and remote areas using internet services`
2. `A member user will register him/her using credentials on said mobile application`

In point 1, I am confused that, would we consider 'News Application' as an Actor because it is using Internet. If so, then how would the Urban and Remote Areas will be placed in Use Case Model. **OR** should I place this whole statement as a Note to the News Application Boundary?

In point 2, should I make the Use Case for `Register using Credentials` and make the Actor `Member` to use it or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding point 1 (News mobile application is accessible in urban and remote areas using internet services): This is not the description of a use case. but it is a constraint on the architecture of the solution. Only solutions that use internet connections are acceptable.

Regarding point 2: `Self-Registration` appears to be a valid use case, with `Member` as (initiating) actor. The fact that it is with credentials does not appear to add value in the use-case title, unless there are other ways for a member to  register him-/herself.